# tabulated output in sqlplus that continues in other line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is possible with sqlplus shows me a tabulated output of query like these:

```
columnA    columnB    columnC
--------   --------    ----------
is a tr    for me i   do you like
y that     s and ex    these
you hav    ample
e
```

I'm trying with column but I can't see anyway.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

COLUMN works too, doesn't it?

```
SQL> column cola format a10
SQL> column colb format a10
SQL> column colc format a10
SQL>
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'is a try that you have' cola,
  3            'for me is an example'   colb,
  4            'do you like these'      colc
  5     from dual)
  6  select * from test;

COLA       COLB       COLC
---------- ---------- ----------
is a try t for me is  do you lik
hat you ha an example e these
ve


SQL>
```